# Android service kills itself upon update, but widgets like buttons/checkboxes remain unchanged

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

In my app, the user can enable a service which does X when Y / X when Z. This needs to be on at all times, but of course Android kills this service when the app is updated. The problem now is that the checkboxes and layoutchanges I make (button-toggles, visibility etc) remain unchanged.

My app's layout depends on SharedPreferences and thus needs to be updated to make changes to the layout. When I update the app, SharedPreferences does not reset like the service making Checkbox1 (which enables services) to stay checked despite the service now being killed. How may I fix that? Would having the checked-state dependant on if the service is running be better than setChecked or SharedPreferences?

Also, how do I notify my user to re-enable the service upon an app-update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.receivers.UpgradeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        <data
            android:path="com.example"
            android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then implement this class UpgradeReceiver and restart you service

```
public UpgradeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Most answers I found just stated that I'll have to deal with it. Again, thanks!